# Entity Framework Core Dynamic GroupBy

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

Instead of hard-coding a GroupBy clause, I would like to be able to dynamically supply a GroupBy clause to an EF query.

Hopefully this code illustrates what I am trying to do:

Here are some simple entities for a simple library book loan system:

```
public class Book
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Isbn { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }

   public IList<Loan> Loans { get; set; }
}


public class Member
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string Surname { get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }

   public IList<Loan> Loans { get; set; }
}


public class Loan
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int BookId { get; set; }
   public int MemberId { get; set; }
   public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
   public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

   public Book Book { get; set; }
   public Member Member { get; set; }
}
```

I have these two view models to help with my EF queries:

```
public class DoubleGroupByClause
{
   public string GroupByFieldValue1 { get; set; }
   public string GroupByFieldValue2 { get; set; }
}

public class QueryRow
{
   public string GroupBy1 { get; set; }
   public string GroupBy2 { get; set; }
   public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

I can run the following code, and it will return a list of QueryRow objects, which equates to the total number of Loans, grouped by book and member age:

```
var rows = _db.Loans
   // note that the GroupBy method params are hard-coded
   .GroupBy( x => new DoubleGroupByClause{GroupByFieldValue1 = x.BookId, GroupByFieldValue2 = x.Member.Age} )
   .Select(x => new QueryRow
   {
      RowId = x.Key.GroupByFieldValue1.ToString(),
      ColId = x.Key.GroupByFieldValue2.ToString(),
      Value = x.Count()
   })
   .ToList();
```

This works just fine, and returns me a list similar to the following:

```
GroupBy1   GroupBy2   Value
(BookId)   (Age)      (Loans)
========   ========   =====
      45         14      23
      45         15      37
      45         16      55
      72         14      34
      72         15      66
      72         16       9
```

**Now on to the problem:**
I want to be able to specify my GroupBy clause from outside of the query itself. The idea is that the two fields that I wish to group by should be held in something similar to variables, and then applied to the query at run-time. I am very close to doing it. Here is where I am up to:

```
// holding the two group by clauses here
Func<Loan, string> groupBy1 = g => g.BookId.ToString();
Func<Loan, string> groupBy2 = g => g.Member.Age.ToString();

// applying the clauses into an expression
Expression<Func<Loan, DoubleGroupByClause>> groupBy = g => new DoubleGroupByClause {GroupByFieldValue1 = groupBy1.Invoke(g), GroupByFieldValue2 = groupBy2.Invoke(g)};

var rows = _db.Loans
   .GroupBy(groupBy)        // applying the expression into the GroupBy clause  
   .Select(x => new QueryRow
   {
      RowId = x.Key.GroupByFieldValue1.ToString(),
      ColId = x.Key.GroupByFieldValue2.ToString(),
      Value = x.Count()
   })
   .ToList();
```

This compiles just fine, but I get the following error at runtime:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Loans>
    .GroupBy(
        source: m => new DoubleGroupByClause{
            GroupByFieldValue1 = __groupBy1_0.Invoke(m),
            GroupByFieldValue2 = __groupBy2_1.Invoke(m)
        }
        ,
        keySelector: m => m)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().
```

I think I'm quite close, but can anyone help me with how I can get this working?

There may be a much simpler way of doing this, so I am open to any suggestions. Hopefully the code illustrates what I am trying to achieve though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments should be expressions (`Expression<Func<>>`) rather than delegates (`Func<>`), e.g.

```
Expression<Func<Loan, string>> groupBy1 = g => g.BookId.ToString();
Expression<Func<Loan, string>> groupBy2 = g => g.Member.Age.ToString();
```

Then you need to compose `Expression<Func<Loan, DoubleGroupByClause>>` from them, which is not so natural as with delegates, but still possible with the help of the `Expression` class and the following little helper utility class for replacing lambda expression parameters:

```
public static partial class ExpressionUtils
{
    public static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression expression, ParameterExpression source, Expression target)
        => new ParameterReplacer { source = source, target = target }.Visit(expression);

    class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression source;
        public Expression target;
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
            => node == source ? target : node;
    }
}
```

Now the implementation of the desired expression:

```
Expression<Func<string, string, DoubleGroupByClause>> groupByPrototype = (v1, v2) =>
    new DoubleGroupByClause { GroupByFieldValue1 = v1, GroupByFieldValue2 = v2 };
var parameter = groupBy1.Parameters[0];
var v1 = groupBy1.Body;
var v2 = groupBy2.Body.ReplaceParameter(groupBy2.Parameters[0], parameter);
var body = groupByPrototype.Body
    .ReplaceParameter(groupByPrototype.Parameters[0], v1)
    .ReplaceParameter(groupByPrototype.Parameters[1], v2);
var groupBy = Expression.Lambda<Func<Loan, DoubleGroupByClause>>(body, parameter);
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. I have implemented your suggestions, but upon executing the query, I get the following error: "System.InvalidOperationException: When called from 'VisitLambda', rewriting a node of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression' must return a non-null value of the same type. Alternatively, override 'VisitLambda' and change it to not visit children of this type."

Comment: Sorry,  little bug there Now should be ok.

Comment: I like your nesting of the `ExpressionVisitor` sub-class in the extension method class.

Comment: Thanks - your solution did work, and it had some key points which put me on the correct path. In the end I was able to solve it slightly more elegantly, but I'd like to say a big thank you as your solution helped me to get there.

Answer (score 1):

The actual solution was frightfully close to my attempt, so I'm posting in here in case it helps anyone else.

All that was missing was a call to .AsExpandable(). This seems to pre-evaluate the Expressions, and then everything works as expected.

So in my example above, it just needed to look like this:

```
var rows = _db.Loans
   .AsExpandable()
   .GroupBy(groupBy)        // applying the expression into the GroupBy clause  
   .Select(x => new QueryRow
   {
      RowId = x.Key.GroupByFieldValue1.ToString(),
      ColId = x.Key.GroupByFieldValue2.ToString(),
      Value = x.Count()
   })
   .ToList();
```

Thanks to Ivan Stoev for your initial suggestions though. That led me on the correct path to help me eventually solve it.

Comment: `AsExpandable` and `Invoke` are custom extension methods from LinqKit package. They allow "invoking" expressions similar to delegates (but you still need to make your `groupBy1` and `groupBy2` expressions). The problem with LinqKit and similar packages is that `AsExpandable` replaces the query provider, which for EF Core is not good in general because it blocks EF Core specific extensions like `Include`, `AsNoTracking()` etc. In this specific case it doesn't matter, but in general I would avoid it (or just use `Expand()` when composing expressions).

Comment: That all makes sense, and provides me with lots of good reading-up to do. Thanks :)